# Compare two arrays for detect remove and add element

Tags: arrays, node.js, sorting

There is two array,

```
One -> ["A","B","C","D"]
Two -> ["A","E","H","D"]
```

I need check array details. I mentioned array one is existing data (before updating) and array two is update data ( after update the array one). I need figure out which data is come into that array (array two ) and which  data is remove from that array (array one).

Comment: Can you please correct some grammar here, because the question is not quite clear.

Comment: I need check array details.I mentioned array one is existing data and array two is update data.i need figure out what data is come into that array and what data is remove from that array. that is the basic idea.did you get it ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into http://underscorejs.org/#arrays functions, you need to use _.intersection and _.difference methods. It's pretty easy to code that functions by yourself if you don't want new dependencies

_.intersection(One, Two) -> not changed data

_.difference(Two, One) -> new data

_.difference(One, Two) -> removed data

Comment: It is working.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function() {
var array1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var array2 = ["A","H","J","D"];
var foo1 = [];
var foo2 = [];
var i = 0;
jQuery.grep(array2, function(el) {

    if (jQuery.inArray(el, array1) == -1) foo1.push(el);


    i++;

});
jQuery.grep(array1, function(e2) {

    if (jQuery.inArray(e2, array2) == -1) foo2.push(e2);


    i++;

});


alert(" Removed Data is " + foo2);
alert(" New Data is " + foo1);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This answers the OPs question works perfectly.+1